# How to convert string to string[] in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to convert the string to string array in java. I tried the following method to achieve this. But its not working as expected.

```
String right_country = "BH, MY, SG, IN, AE";
String[] ritcountry_ary = new String[] {right_country};
```

When try to print the above array this is what i am getting.

```
for(int i=0 ;i<=countries.length - 1; i++){

            System.out.println("o"+countries[i]);
        }
```

output:`oBH, MY, SG, IN, AE`

But I need something like the following.

> ```
> oBH
> oMY
> oSG
> oIN
> oAE
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
String[] ritcountry_ary = right_country.split(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an array of one element, `split` your `right_country` on `,` (and optional white space). And, I would *prefer* a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Something like,

```
String right_country = "BH, MY, SG, IN, AE";
String[] ritcountry_ary = right_country.split(",\\s*");
for (String country : ritcountry_ary) {
    System.out.println("o" + country);
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
oBH
oMY
oSG
oIN
oAE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the split function.

```
String[] ritcountry_ary = right_country.split(", ");
```

This function makes an array out of the string by splitting it based on the text you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.split` to get an array and use the correct array in the for loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String right_country = "BH, MY, SG, IN, AE";
        String[] ritcountry_ary =right_country.split(", ");
        for(int i=0 ;i<ritcountry_ary.length; i++){
            System.out.println("n"+ritcountry_ary[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`new String[] {right_country}` merely creates a new array of `String` objects with a single element in the array. Assuming that `right_country` looks like `"BH, MY, SG, IN, AE"`, you can split them into an array using a regular expression:

```
String right_country = "BH, MY, SG, IN, AE";
String[] right_countries = right_country.split(",\\s*");
for (String country : right_countries) {
    System.out.println("o" + country);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is the method split().

You should check this topic for more details :
[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

It's very simple, you call split() on the source string, with separator as parameter, and it returns you an array :)
This give you somethink like :

```
ritcountry_ary = right_country.split(", ");
```